# Fabric - Sequential meta-tasks?

Tags: deployment, fabric

I have a task that executes tasks -

```
@roles('group_django')
@task
@serial
def deploy_web():
    execute(pre_deploy)
    execute(fix_srv_perms)
    execute(force_checkout_branch_to_production)
    execute(update_sources)
    execute(pip_install_requirements)
    #execute(bounce_workers)
    execute(bounce_uwsgi)
    execute(clear_cache)
```

Is it possible in deploy_web, given the provided hosts to execute sequentially but collectively together.

Say the role "group_django" has 4 server, it would start with the first host in that role and execute each of the executes then repeat.  Or do I need to do some more legwork up front and grab the current `env.hosts` and in a loop inside of `deploy_web` call each `execute` with `hosts=[current_host]`

What I am aiming for is that if its a bad deploy, it would knock out only one of a pool of servers so that the load balancer would kick it out but the platform would keep some semblance of integrity.

Already read ( [Is there a way to conduct rolling deployment in fabric files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148443/is-there-a-way-to-conduct-rolling-deployment-in-fabric-files/9199905#9199905) ) and it's not applicable to how my `deploy_web` task works.

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding your question, you want to change fabric serial execution model: instead of `pre_deploy host1` -> `pre_deploy host2` -> `fix_srv_perms host1` etc you want `pre_deploy host1` -> `fix_srv_perms host1` ... -> `pre_deploy host2` -> `fix_srv_perms host2` etc. In this case I think you should iterate over each host inside `deploy_web` and pass `hosts` to execute.

Comment: @alecxe I figured as much, currently away for the week but I plan to cobble together a support library to accomplish this as it seems like a nice approach for rolling out complex services.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic answer to my question is with this little helper function.

```
def execute_serial(func, *args, **kwargs):
    a2set = lambda x : set(getattr(func, x)) if hasattr(func, x) else None

    func_hosts = a2set('hosts')
    func_roles = a2set('roles')
    should_exec = False

    if 'host' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['host'] = my_host = env.host_string

    if func_hosts and my_host in func_hosts:
        should_exec = True


    if func_roles:
        for func_role in func_roles:
            if func_role in env.roledefs and my_host in env.roledefs[func_role]:
                should_exec = True

    if should_exec:
        return execute(func, *args, **kwargs)
```

And usage would be like

```
@roles('group_django')
@task
def deploy_web():
    execute(pre_deploy)
    execute_serial(fix_srv_perms)
    execute_serial(force_checkout_branch_to_production)
    execute_serial(update_sources)
    execute_serial(pip_install_requirements)

    #these won't work correctly anymore
    execute(bounce_workers)
    execute(bounce_uwsgi)
    execute(clear_cache)
```

I've gone through fabric.main.main() and there's no easy opportunities for hooks ( prior to start, all tasks done, on error, etc etc ) so an additional solution might be instead

```
@roles('local') # defined in roledefs as {'local':'127.0.0.1'}
@task    
def deploy_web():
    execute(pre_deploy) #This is already role('local') with @runonce

    for host in env.roledefs['group_django'].values():
        execute_serial(fix_srv_perms, host = host)
        execute_serial(force_checkout_branch_to_production, host = host)
        execute_serial(update_sources, host = host)
        execute_serial(pip_install_requirements, host = host)

    #These will pickup the @role decorators
    execute(redeploy_web_crontab)
    execute(redeploy_work_crontab)
    execute(bounce_workers) 
    execute(bounce_uwsgi)
    execute(clear_cache)
```

Additional info, I've written something like this a few times but I have a boto iterator that uses to ~/.boto to decide on region and produce a `env.roledefs` as illustrated in pseudo-code

{  "{name in instance.tags }_{instance.tags[name]}": [ list of instance.public_dns_name that matches] }

additionally for my current webstack, all instances have tags like "group", "type", and optionally "lead" for specifying where to install crontabs, or execute final deployment scripts.

Using the local task loop you would need to make some slight modification to `execute_serial` specifically env.host_string would equal "{env.user}@127.0.0.1" which is not ideal.

```
def execute_serial(func, *args, **kwargs):
a2set = lambda x : set(getattr(func, x)) if hasattr(func, x) else None

no_user = lambda x: x.split("@")[-1]
func_hosts = a2set('hosts')
func_roles = a2set('roles')
should_exec = False
my_host = env.host_string

my_host = env.host_string = kwargs['host']


if func_hosts and no_user(my_host) in func_hosts:
    should_exec = True


if func_roles:
    for func_role in func_roles:
        if func_role in env.roledefs and no_user(env.host_string) in env.roledefs[func_role]:
            should_exec = True
            break

if should_exec:
    return execute(func, *args, **kwargs)
```